# Loop through child records / identify smallest field value / update status of all child records dependant on smallest value

Tags: apex

Hoping those with a bit more apex experience can point me in the right direction with this problem i have;

**Problem:**

I have an object **Suburb** which has a master-detail relationship to object **Service_Territory_Suburb**.

One **Suburb** can have multiple **Service_Territory_Suburb** records linked to it.

The Service_Territory_Suburb object has three important fields on it;

- *Client* (Lookup to account)
- *Distance* (Number field indicating a driving distance)
- *Active* (Boolean indicating that this Service Territory Suburb record is the one with the smallest Distance value)

There is a SOQL query prior to the code below that returns all a Suburb and all of its child Service Territory Suburb records for a particular Client.

I am trying to automate a method to loop through and update the Active field of each child **Service_Territory_Suburb** based on which record has the smallest Distance value.
(Only the child record with the smallest *Distance* value gets it's *Active* field set to true; all others get the *Active* field set to false)

There is alot of these records to bulkification with DML is definitely required.

I've managed to be able to query the parent Suburb /child Service_Territory_Suburb records using the below code (debug result image attached) but am unsure how to manage the above described logic.

```
// Loop through each suburb
for (Suburb__c suburb : Suburbs)
{
    
    // Check if the suburb has more than 1 Service Territory Suburb child.
    if (suburb.Service_Territory_Suburbs__r.size() > 1)
    {
        
        System.Debug('SUBURB: ' + suburb.Name + ' ________  (STS COUNT: ' + suburb.Service_Territory_Suburbs__r.size() + ')');

        // Loop through each child Service Territory Suburb for the Suburb            
        for (Integer i = 0; i < suburb.Service_Territory_Suburbs__r.size(); i++)
        {
            System.Debug('  - STS Id: ' + suburb.Service_Territory_Suburbs__r[i].Id + ' |  Distance: ' + suburb.Service_Territory_Suburbs__r[i].Distance__c + ' |  Active: ' + suburb.Service_Territory_Suburbs__r[i].Active__c);

            // ??.. unsure of the logic to handle looping through these child STS records

        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Above code debug results image:

[image: code debug results]

Comment: You actually might not need any code here.

Comment: Can you ellaborate @AdrianLarson; if you are referring to the sample results returned in the image looking like the Active is set correctly, there is many 100's more where it is not; the image was purely to show the child/parent record results

Comment: I would think to implement roll up summary field 
(min) on distance field, then on parent trigger i would simply query all its child and mark all the child inactive except where roll up field value matches child distance.

Comment: I didn't think of using roll-up summary fields! And just thought that would be perfect. However there is a lookup field Client__c on the Service_Territory_Suburb record. And the Suburbs list used in the first loop already gets the client-specific records via soql where clause. (Apologies for not including that aspect in the original problem description; I didn't anticipate the roll-up method)

Comment: If i understood it correctly, it would mean there will be multiple active child records (having min distance) for different accounts under same Parent suburb record. In this case you can't go via route of roll-up

Comment: That's 100% correct Elijah.